# Tkinter Shutil Move Files

Tags: python, tkinter, shutil

I am using Tkinter to create a file manager. So far, I've created a way to browse files, and check files in a folder. My problem is that I am trying to use shutil to move files that have been modified or created in the last 24 hours, from one source folder to a destination folder. My code using python worked fine until I incorporated Tkinter. Now it moves my entire folder, instead of just the files that have been modified in the last 24 hours.

Any help would be appreciated! I am a student, so I am still learning.

```
from tkinter import *
import shutil
import time
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title('File Manager')
root.geometry("300x250")


def select_folder():
    src = filedialog.askdirectory()

def move_to():
    src = filedialog.askdirectory()
    SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60
    now = time.time()
    before = now - SECONDS_IN_DAY
    def last_mod_time(fname):
        return os.path.getmtime(fname)
    for fname in os.listdir(src):
        src_fname = os.path.join(src, fname)
    if last_mod_time(src_fname) > before:
        dst_fname = os.path.join(dst, fname)
    dst = filedialog.askdirectory()
    shutil.move(src, dst)

def file_check():
    folderList = filedialog.askdirectory()
    sortlist = sorted(os.listdir(folderList))
    i=0
    print("Files in ", folderList, "folder are:")
    while(i<len(sortlist)):
        print(sortlist[i]+'\n')
        i+=1
            

select_button = Button(root, text="Select Folder", command= select_folder)
select_button.pack(pady=20)

move_button = Button(root, text="Move To Folder", command= move_to)
move_button.pack(pady=22)

check_button = Button(root, text="File Check", command= file_check)
check_button.pack(pady=24)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
shutil.move(src, dst)
```

You told it right there to move the directory. I assume you meant to do

```
shutil.move(src_fname, dst_fname)
```

You also have some indentation issues. As a guess you need:

```
def move_to():
    src = filedialog.askdirectory()
    dst = filedialog.askdirectory()

    SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60
    now = time.time()
    before = now - SECONDS_IN_DAY
    def last_mod_time(fname):
        return os.path.getmtime(fname)
    for fname in os.listdir(src):
        src_fname = os.path.join(src, fname)
        if last_mod_time(src_fname) > before:
            dst_fname = os.path.join(dst, fname)
            shutil.move(src_fname, dst_fname)
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I knew I was very close on this one. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @girlcode If it did solve your issue, make sure to mark as the correct answer :D